# Mysterious NTFS writes long after copying data to it

Tags: 16.04, hard-drive, ntfs, disk-usage

I copied 50GB of Videos to my external  USB3.0 5tb HDD that uses one big NTFS partition. This worked as expected and with good speed.

However, after it's done, there are audible write accesses to the disk for hours. If i disconnect the HDD and reconnect it, these writes just continue! After sitting it out for a couple of hours, it stops.

What's going on? Should I be worried?

Effects are reproducible under my Ubuntu 16.04. Same does not occur under Windows. If someone has a good idea how to debug/investigate this, let me know...

Comment: If you had not disconnected the drive, I would assume that it keeps writing from the USB cache, but disconnecting while it is busy with that should likely corrupt your drive and not simply continue...

Comment: It could be updatedb.mlocate. You could try killing it to see if it helps (sudo killall updatedb.mlocate and delete the db at /var/lib/mlocate/mlocate.db). If it is, the permanent solution is to edit the config so it ignores NTFS disks. You could also try installing iotop and checking what is reading/writing (don't forget to config it first, though).

Comment: Thanks for the input. 'mlocate' isnt running. I checked 'iotop' but it seems nothing is writing to disk, except occasional ext4 journal. :( Also checked with 'lsof' that no files are open on the ext drive. 'sync' didnt help either. What do you mean by "config it first"?

Answer (score 1):

### Flushing the buffers

You can check this behaviour with the command `sync`, which flushes the buffers and writes to the drive. Bash (the command line interpreter) will return to prompt, when the buffers are flushed. When you unmount or 'eject' the target partition on the USB drive, it will run `sync` before unmounting.

It is safe to unplug the drive, when all the partitions on the drive are unmounted. Otherwise, if you unplug the drive without unmounting, you will probably corrupt the file system.

### Trim alias discard

SSD (solid state drive) uses a special method in order to release unused memory cells to make it possible to spread the wear of the memory cell hardware. In some cases, when the operating system is idle, you will see **trim** cause action on the drive to be indicated.

See this link, [wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Solid_State_Drives](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Solid_State_Drives)

Some expensive USB 3 pendrives have the ability to trim the memory, for example [this one](http://www.kingston.com/datasheets/DTWS_en.pdf).

Comment: It's not a SSD. But it sure feels like some sort of indexing/trimming/defragmenting is going on. Do you know of something like  that that could affect HDDs in this way?

Comment: I don't know. There are many people here, who know a lot about hard disk drives and how they are managed. Let us hope that more of them will find your question and share their knowledge.